# XSLT XML: The output of the trasformation should be empty, when some children nodes are missing

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, foreach

I have following input:

```
<note> 
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
</note>
<note> 
   <to>Tom</to>
   <from>Eddy</from>
</note>
```

I want following output with the enclosing tag .:

```
<allnotes>
   <note_t>
     <to_t>Tove</to_t>
     <from_t>Jani</from_t>
   </note_t>
   <note_t> 
      <to_t>Tom</to_t>
      <from_t>Eddy</from-tt>
   </note_t>
</allnotes>
```

When one note in the input is not complete, eg. only with tag `<from>` the node element `<note>` should be ignored. When all node elements are not complete then the output should be completly empty without parent node  `</allnotes>`. I'm not able to make the last condition work. My output is always `<allnotes></allnotes>`

This my XSLT. Is there a way to solve the last condition by editing my named template:

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:variable name="to1" select="//note/to"/>
    <xsl:variable name="from1" select="//note/from"/>
    <xsl:if test="$to1!='' and $from1!=''">
        <xsl:element name="allnotes">
            <xsl:for-each select="//note">
                <xsl:variable name="to" select="./to"/>
                <xsl:variable name="from" select="./from"/>     
                <xsl:if test="$to!='' and $from!=''">
                    <xsl:element name="note_t">
                        <xsl:if test="$to!=''">
                            <xsl:element name="to_t">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$to"/>    
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$from!=''">
                            <xsl:element name="from_t">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$from"/>  
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: XML is not well formed (no root element), and post your tried XSLT.

Comment: Does the source XML have a wrapper element for all notes and only the notes?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one wrapper element and other siblings of note.

Comment: Please show us a **representative** and **well-formed** example of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to provide an answer without seeing a complete example of the input. Here is one way you could possibly look at it. Given an input such as:

```
<source>
    <other/> 
    <note> 
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
    </note>
    <note> 
       <to>Tom</to>
       <from>Eddy</from>
    </note>
</source>
```

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:if test="source/note[to and from]">
            <allnotes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="source/note[to and from]"/>
            </allnotes>
        </xsl:if>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <allnotes>
    <note> 
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
    </note>
    <note> 
       <to>Tom</to>
       <from>Eddy</from>
    </note>
  </allnotes>
</output>
```

When the input is:

```
<source>
    <other/> 
    <note> 
       <to>Tove</to>
    </note>
    <note> 
       <from>Eddy</from>
    </note>
</source>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output/>
```

Comment: Ok, I try this one in my XSLT: <xsl:if test="source/note[to and from]">

Comment: I am testing and testing and each time the ouput is correct. I just replaced the first tree lines in my XSLT with <xsl:if test="source/note[to and from]"> . Thank you for your help!!!!